# In Excel, how can I dynamically have formulas update based on the current date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a workbook that tracks billings and expenses for every month and compares them to forecasts.

Every month, to generate reports, we need to update the formula references so it points to the current month.

Is there a way to dynamically automate the formula references based on the current date?

Edit:
Here is an example of the Tables I'm working with and what we currently do.

| Resource | Daily rate | June workdays | July workdays | August workdays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kate | $5,000 | 10 | 15 | 5 |
| Adam | $2,500 | 20 | 15 | 22 |
| James | $1,750 | 20 | 10 | 22 |
| Total |  | 50 | 40 | 49 |

| Resource | Daily rate | June Billings | July Billings | August Billings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kate | $5,000 | $50,000 | $75,000 | $25,000 |
| Adam | $2,500 | $50,000 | $37,500 | $55,000 |
| James | $1,750 | $25,000 | $17,500 | $38,500 |
| Total |  | $125,000 | $130,000. | $118,500 |

Invoices generated for

June Invoice:

- June actual hours:   xlookup(June hours worked)
- June Total Billings: xlookup(June billings)
- Forecasts for July:  xlookup(July hours)
- Forecasted billings for July: xlookup(July billings)
- Forecasts for August: xlookup(August hours)
- Forecasted billings for August: xlookup(August billings)

Historical billings provided:

- Jan: xlookup (jan)
- Feb: xlookup (Feb)
- Mar: xlookup (Mar)
- Apr: xlookup (Apr)
- May: xlookup (May)

Next month we will update each xlookup for each upcoming month so the invoice in August, will return August figures and provide forecasts for September and October.

**What I'd like to do:**
Based on the current date, all the xlookups references automatically update to the current month.

Comment: And did you try your own suggestion? Did it work? Or what issue did you run into? Why not just hard code the month in A3? All your formulas would then just reference that cell like what I think you are saying. Sometimes hard coding is the preferred method if you want to be able to pull the report months from now and see the same results...

Comment: Please [edit] your post & add some sample data along with formula applied ,,,, that will clear the picture for updates,,, then after a date based update can be set !

Comment: You could you create a table with two columns: month and calculation. Each month's formula is calculated but only the current month's result is returned via `XLOOKUP()` or `VLOOKUP()`.

Comment: There's lots of way to have formula reference the current date, but it all depends on the data. As @RajeshSinha said - please add some sample data.

Comment: You should provide a sample table here not only the formula.